# How to query a table with $all and an array as a parameter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to query a collection called orders using the default _id with an array that has the _ids that I need but when i try to save the result in another

```
let orderIds = ['example1', 'example2']
db.collection("orders").find({ _id: { $all: orderIds } }, function (err, orders) {
    console.log(orders);
})
```

Comment: $all expects the field to be queried to be an array, and it checks whether it contains all the elements. You're looking for the [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$in` instead of `$all` to get all the documents from a given array of `ids`

Try this:

```
db.collection("orders").find({ _id: { $in: orderIds } }, function (err, orders) {
    console.log(orders);
})
```

Read more about [$in here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)